# How to inspect variable value anywhere in my program?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm debugging a program in VS2015.

How do I have it display my main class (eg. mainWindow) so I can then navigate all it's children (and thus reach any part of my code structure)? That way I could check the value of any variable at any time during the execution of the program.

I tried adding that class (a field within it) to watch list, but it was greyed out during most of execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature in Visual Studio 2015 called **Make Object Id**, as you can see in image below.

[image: Make Object Id]

> This feature exist in other visual studio versions, go to end of this answer to get a link of article that use older VS version.

To access that, you must hover the variable, and when the variable display popup appear click with right mouse button inside it, and the Object Id will be created.

Also you can pin your variable in watch window, and then click with right mouse button to see the option **Make Object Id**.

---

You can also pin the variable values, to do it, just click in pin button

[image]

---

Then after **Pin** and **Make Object Id**, you can add new expression to this pin popup that is a `$1`, this is the reference to this variable that you **Make Object Id**, as you can see below, after you **Make Object Id** the variable line got the object Id added in end of line like `{$1}`.

[image]

---

You can also make your pin popup appear in other files and also follow the scroll by clicking in the pin button that is below close button, and if you do that, it should be like that:

[image]

---

This is also avaliable in others Visual Studio version, but with some differences, and you can see this article to know more about that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/

Comment: @Karlovsky120 any feedback?